# How to inspect raw SQL queries generated by Django when debugging?

Tags: python, django, debugging, optimization, profiling

I am trying to profile a large portion of my project, carefully analyzing queries generated by each line of code. Careful analysis requires running the server in debug mode so I can step over these lines one by one and take my time to study the queries.

So far I have tried three unsucessful ways of doing this:

**Inspecting `django.db.connection.queries`**

You can see what queries have been generated and executed against the database by inspecting the `django.db.connection.queries` dictionary. The problem with this:

- It needs to be actively inspected. You cannot just have it as a listener and log these queries behind the scenes. You need to actually print out `connection.queries` after every single line, which is a nuisance.
- Apparently it only stores queries generated in the same file where you are using `connection.queries`. If you inspect it right after calling `some_method()` and that method is imported from some other place, you will not see the queries `some_method` generated.

**Logging configuration**

I set up the following logging configuration in my settings file that logs all queries run against the database:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console']
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is PyCharm. When debugging, PyCharm evaluates all involved variables so you can see and inspect their value. This is handy in most cases, but it completely skews my analysis, as to evaluate these variables queries are run against the database and these are of course being logged.

**Debug Toolbar**

The main and only issue with this is that the behavior needs to be wrapped in a view. The log of queries is not shown up until the view is done executing, so debugging it is impossible.